# chrome.input undefined in latest Chrome Browser (26)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, ime

Referring to documentation and sample code found here:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/input.ime.html

I am trying to install the sample extension/code to test chrome.input.ime

It seems that chrome.input is not defined even though I have declared "input" in the manifest permissions.

Are there any issues with the sample code? Has anyone successfully run the sample in the latest chrome?

Comment: Further investigation shows a recently closed issue in the chromium review https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/14635008/#ps1 I've tested it on chromium (build 25) and doesn't work there either even though it's marked as manually tested.

Comment: Another update. It now reads as: chrome.input.ime is not supported on this platform or manifest version  (for version 27) even though the manifest is version 2.

Comment: Upon further reading the input.ime is for Chrome OS